# Problem in Elementary HTML Nomenclature relating to a Product Search

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to create a product search bar. I am new to WebDev and think I have misunderstood some nomenclature or element. Please help me out with corrections and explanations. I am not just looking for fixed code. Also, help/resources on how to prevent similar errors in the future and improving proficiency in basic nomenclature will be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%; 
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Product Search</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for a Product..." title="Type in a name">
<script>

function myFunction() {
    var input, input_uppercase, a, i, txtValue;
    var products= ["Headphones", "Desktops", "Laptops", "Speakers"];
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    input_uppercase = input.value.toUpperCase();
    for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        a = products[i];
        txtValue = a.textContent;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(input_uppercase) > -1) {
            document.write(products[i]);
        } else {document.write(); }
        }
        }   


    


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the above code to act like a search bar. A user will enter letters trying to search for a product. None of the products should be shown beforehand. On each keypress, if the input string matches any part of the string of the products names i.e. Headphones, Desktops, Laptops, Speakers, then those products should be shown. For e.g. if a user searches 'd' then only products containing the string d in some part will be shown. In this case, headphones, desktops. Further, if the user searches 'de' then only products containing the string 'de' should be shown. In this case, desktops only. Also, I want the search to not be case-sensitive.

When I run the code, I do not get the name of any product when I start entering characters, despite matching with several of the products.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide details for the problem you are encountering, what you expect to happen and at what point in your code it's not giving you the result you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textContent` does not exist on var `a`. So when you go to assign a.textContent to txtValue, it is being set to undefined.

If you check your console, you should be getting an error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined"